# coding a real by reflection of stationary sets

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

While reading a recent preprint I encountered the following theorem:

THEOREM:  Assume Martin's Maximum, $\kappa \ge \omega_2$ is regular, $\langle S_n \ : \ n \in \omega \rangle$ is a pairwise disjoint collection of stationary subsets of $\kappa \cap \text{cof}(\omega)$, and $z \subseteq \omega$.  Then there is a $\beta < \kappa$ such that for all $n \in \omega$:  $n \in z$ if and only if $S_n \cap \beta$ is stationary.

The authors attribute this to the original Foreman-Magidor-Shelah paper on Martin's Maximum, but I could not find it there.  Could someone provide a citation and/or sketch of the proof?

**EDIT 1**:  I think I see how the proof must go, but I'd still be interested in a citation.

If $z = \emptyset$ then any $\beta$ of countable cofinality works, and in fact ONLY those $\beta$ of countable cofinality can possibly work if the original given sequence $\vec{S} = \langle S_n \ : \ n \in \omega \rangle$ was a partition of all of $\kappa \cap \text{cof}(\omega)$.

So from now on assume $z \ne \emptyset$.  Fix a partition $\langle T_n \ : \ n \in z \rangle$ of stationary subsets of $\omega_1$; note this makes sense because of the assumption that $z \ne \emptyset$.  Let $Q$ be the poset of countable continuous sequences $\langle N_i \ : \ i \le \gamma \rangle$ of countable elementary submodels, such that (A) for all $i \le \gamma$, $\text{sup}(N_i \cap \kappa) \notin S_n$ for all $n \in \omega - z$;  (B)  For all $i < \gamma$:  letting $n(i)$ be the unique element of $z$ such that $i \in T_{n(i)}$, require that $\text{sup}(N_j \cap \kappa) \in S_{n(i)}$ for all limit $j \in (i,\gamma] \cap T_{n(i)}$.   Then $Q$ is stationary set preserving and applying MM to it should yield the result.

**EDIT 2**  Assaf Rinot pointed out to me that the proof is implicit in the F-M-S proof that SCH follows from MM.

Comment: (Yes, this is done in Theorem 10, that has as corollary the SCH.)

Comment: Yes, I was only looking in the parts about stationary set reflection.  Didn't think to look at the SCH stuff!